# WPF login authentication form SQL Server database

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, sql-server-2012

I need to know about how to check the entered password and `User_ID` is correct from my table created in SQL Server 2012.

Kindly give me a link or code if anybody knows about it from beginning like making connection string and so on ...... !

Thanks in advance to all programmers :P

Comment: Have a look at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt715492.aspx

Comment: yeah but this is not my answer according to my question ..... just need a simple code to check that ID and password is in my table or not to move on next screen ....

Comment: in the article shown how to connect to database and execute queries. if you connected to your database, then there should not be any problem to just execute needed query and user credentials. Or you can use simple `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` to execute yout query. Here is example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fksx3b4f.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Ruben i hope it will work for me also .... :)

Comment: You could also look into implementing Entity Framework. EF makes it very simple to query a database, without having to deal with any SqlConnections or SqlCommands. The link is a beginners guide to setting up EF from an existing database. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Due to the lack of time I am not going to follow Entity Framework for my application but still I got the answer from this link.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fksx3b4f.aspx

and here is my code to Check the Entered User_ID and Password is Correct or not ....

```
    private String ConnectionString;
    private SqlConnection connection;
    private SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    private SqlDataReader reader;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\RFIDdatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ID.Text + " and " + Pass.Password);

            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Login "
                            + "where USER_ID = '" + ID.Text + "' "
                            + "and Password = '" + Pass.Password + "'";

            Console.WriteLine(cmd.CommandText);
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            connection.Open();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            int i = 0;

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                i++;
            }


            if (i == 1)
            {
                Window1 win = new Window1();
                win.Show();
            }
            else {
                MessageBox.Show("INCORRECT PASSWORD OR USER ID", "Authentication Failed");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Catch Block = " + ex);
        }
        finally {

            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your password isn't hatched. Your app has less security than a wide open door.

Answer (score 2):

Implement authentication is a different matter than database programming. You should first focus on core issues one by one.

This is what you actually need :

[WPF: Implementing Custom Authentication And Authorization](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25726.wpf-implementing-custom-authentication-and-authorization.aspx)

Optionally,

[Entity Framework Code First to an Existing Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: well I visit the link you post here and its really helpful for me in future but i did my work as I post my answer below......  Thanks alot @anjunskhan